# Filter array with multiple properties while catering to undefined terms

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-filter

I need to filter an array by 4 object properties based on user input but sometimes user can choose to enter only 1, 2 or 3 terms which gives undefined on properties the user did not enter.

```
const myTableData = [
    {
        'date': '2020-05-16',
        'duration': 247,
        'low_temp': 373.0,
        'high_temp': 388.0,
        'type': 'XD'
    },
    {
        'date': '2020-05-27',
        'duration': 246,
        'low_temp': 373.0,
        'high_temp': 388.0,
        'type': 'LB'
    },
    {
        'date': '2020-06-04',
        'duration': 247,
        'low_temp': 374.0,
        'high_temp': 388.0,
        'type': 'LB'
    }
];

export async function filter_click(event) {
    let newArray = myTableData.filter(function (el) {
        return el.duration === Number($w("#duration").value) && el.low_temp === Number($w("#lowtemp").value) && el.high_temp === Number($w("#hightemp").value) && el.type === $w("#type").value;
    });
    $w("#table1").rows = newArray;
}
```

See if even 1 of the user input elements are not filled it gives an undefined which returns an empty array.

***Why I cannot use || instead of &&***

If I use the OR '||' operator it doesn't narrow down to ALL the properties asked by the user. Example: If 'duration' is 350 & 'type' is 'LB' and the user types in both it will not return ONLY the objects which have both duration as 350 and type as LB, instead it will return objects having either.

Comment: What behavior do you want if the table data field is undefined? It will be excluded from the filtered results as a "non-matching" entry?

Comment: Yes! Exactly. right now if any property is undefined the whole array just return empty. I would like if undefined property to be excluded from the filter.

Comment: what is `$w` in the example?

Comment: Its the user input element. Similar to document.getelementbyid

Answer (score 1):

It will probably help you a *lot* when you're trying to work through a problem, to make your code easier to read. Right now you have one massive return line that is super hard to read and understand.

A filter function just needs to return `true` (at any point) if the evaluated item should be included, and `false` (at any point) if it should be excluded. So you can evaluate each of your fields, one by one, to see if it *fails any* of the required conditions and should be *excluded*, whereupon you return false. Otherwise, at the end of the function, if it passes all the tests you know it should be included and return `true` (the "base case"). This kind of inverse filtering where you test for cases to exclude rather than cases to include can often be much easier to write, read, and reason about.

I would also write the filter function itself as a separate function to make it more clear, easier to read, and easier to maintain.

```
// Exclude compared item if it fails any of the "tests"
// Otherwise include it (return true)
function filterTable(el) {
  if (el.duration !== Number($w("#duration").value) || el.duration === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  if (el.low_temp !== Number($w("#lowtemp").value) || el.low_temp === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
  // etc. for each field to be compared

  // Base case - by this point it has passed all tests and should be included
  return true;
}

export async function filter_click(event) {
    let newArray = myTableData.filter(filterTable);
    $w("#table1").rows = newArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few points

1. Cache your elements and don't do expensive dom lookups inside your `Array.filter()`
2. Parse your params so you not doing unnecessary casting inside your `Array.filter()`
3. Build up your params and pass them in the correct format to your filter function.
4. **If** a param has been included - test against current filter item, otherwise ignore it

This way you are not doing expensive lookups and casting **on every iteration** in the filter. You don't need to consider properties unless the associated param has been included.

Snippet:

```js
const myTableData = [{
    'date': '2020-05-16',
    'duration': 247,
    'low_temp': 373.0,
    'high_temp': 388.0,
    'type': 'XD'
  },
  {
    'date': '2020-05-27',
    'duration': 246,
    'low_temp': 373.0,
    'high_temp': 388.0,
    'type': 'LB'
  },
  {
    'date': '2020-06-04',
    'duration': 247,
    'low_temp': 374.0,
    'high_temp': 388.0,
    'type': 'LB'
  }
];

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  // cache the elements to avoid expensive lookups in your filter
  const $duration = document.querySelector('#duration');
  const $lowtemp = document.querySelector('#lowtemp');
  const $hightemp = document.querySelector('#hightemp');
  const $type = document.querySelector('#type');

  const filterData = (params) => {
    return myTableData.filter((item) => {
      // if we have duration, check it
      if (params.duration && item.duration !== params.duration) {
        return false;
      }

      // if we have lowtemp, check it
      if (params.low_temp && item.low_temp !== params.low_temp) {
        return false;
      }

      // if we have hightemp, check it
      if (params.high_temp && item.high_temp !== params.high_temp) {
        return false;
      }

      // if we have type, check it
      if (params.type && item.type.toLowerCase() !== params.type) {
        return false;
      }

      // include this item
      return true;
    });
  }

  document.querySelector('#filter').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    // build up the params to filter by
    const params = {};

    if ($duration.value) {
      // parse to int 
      params.duration = parseInt($duration.value);
    }

    if ($lowtemp.value) {
      // parse to float 
      params.low_temp = parseFloat($lowtemp.value);
    }

    if ($hightemp.value) {
      // parse to float 
      params.high_temp = parseFloat($hightemp.value);
    }

    if ($type.value) {
      // convert to lowercase for comparison
      params.type = $type.value.toLowerCase();
    }

    console.info(filterData(params).length);
  });

  // few tests below
  let params = {};
  console.info(filterData(params).length === 3);

  params = {
    duration: 246
  };
  console.info(filterData(params).length === 1);

  params = {
    duration: 247
  };
  console.info(filterData(params).length === 2);

  params = {
    duration: 247,
    low_temp: 373.0
  };
  console.info(filterData(params).length === 1);

  params = {
    low_temp: 374.0,
    high_temp: 388.0
  };
  console.info(filterData(params).length === 1);

  params = {
    type: 'lb',
  };
  console.info(filterData(params).length === 2);

  params = {
    high_temp: 388.0,
  };
  console.info(filterData(params).length === 3);
});
```

```html
<input id="duration" value="246" />
<input id="lowtemp" value="373.0" />
<input id="hightemp" value="388.0" />
<input id="type" value="LB" />
<button id="filter">filter</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

how about a for loop and a bool array?

```
for (i = 0; i<array.length; i++)
     if thing != array[i]:
          bool[i] = false

for (each in bool):
    if each == false:
         do something;
```

Comment: It would be beneficial to explain your answer instead of some very limited pseudo-code.